# What were the ancient Egyptian terms for the sports of wrestling and boxing?

Tags: ancient-egypt

Wrestling has had a long history, with images depicted of it going back at least 7000 years [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_wrestling), and in Egypt at least from [2400 BCE](https://www.bloodyelbow.com/2019/10/9/20903209/from-grappling-art-to-pharaonic-propaganda-the-history-of-wrestling-in-ancient-egypt) it was depicted on tomb walls. I have been unable to find an ancient Egyptian term, either single word or phrase, that means "wrestling" or "wrestle". Does anyone know what the term might be? I am also trying to find similar words or phrases for boxing.